# Dependence of radial probability function on quantum numbers

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, hydrogen

I was reading the book "Quantum Physics" from Eisberg & Resnick about the expected value of the electron radial coordinate, which it defines as

\begin{align}
\overline{r_{nl}} = \int_{0}^{\infty}rP_{nl}(r)dr
\end{align}

where $P_{nl}dr = R_{nl}^*(r)R_{nl}(r)r^2dr$ is the radial probability density, and $n$ and $l$ are the principal and azymuthal quantum numbers. So the book says that the value of the integral is

\begin{align}
\overline{r_{nl}}=\frac{n^2a_0}{Z}\left \{1+\frac{1}{2}\Big[1-\frac{l(l+1)}{n^2} \Big] \right \}
\end{align}
How did it get there? The function $R_{nl}(r)$ is dependent on polynomials in r. Then,  to calculate the integral, I have to know these polynomials?

Comment: The polynomials are generalized Laguerre polynomials. Calculating the integral for arbitrary $n$ and $l$ is nontrivial. Here is one way: http://www.eng.fsu.edu/~dommelen/quantum/style_a/nt_rsexp.html

Comment: You could also calculate, say, the expectation value for $1s$ up to $4f$ using the explicit polynomials, and guess the general formula from the results. But obviously this would not be a proof.

Comment: Like so many other sets of orthogonal functions the generalized Laguerre polynomials have recurance relations. Presumably the general solution is boostrapped from that foundation. This is also the kind of exercise that you find in Arfken. The polynomials and their properties are tabulated in many places including [Abramowitz and Stegun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abramowitz_and_Stegun) which can be downloaded for free from the US government.